# Add CSS class to DOM element when other element comes into view

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Here's a live demo: http://www.lazarogamio.com/sfgn/single_page

I have a sticky panel that is fixed as you begin scrolling down, then stops when the footer comes into view. Or at least I'd like it to. You can see in the demo that the stucky aside goes over the footer.

I've tried doing it a number of ways, once using  the jQuery appear plugin: http://morr.github.com/appear.html. I wrote this:

```
$('footer').on('appear', 'aside', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('fixed_aside').addClass('bottom_fixed_aside');
   });
```

I created a .bottom_fixed_aside class that then makes the aside element stick to the bottom of the container using display:inline-block.

I also tried this, with help from a friend, that does not rely on the jQuery appear plugin:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

    var windowHeight = $(document).height();
    var footerHeight = $(footer).height();
    var positionToReach = windowHeight - footerHeight;
    if( $(document).scrollTop() >= positionToReach ){
         $('aside').removeClass('fixed_aside').addClass('bottom_fixed_aside');
                } else {
         $('aside').removeClass('bottom_fixed_aside');
                }
   }
});
```

It also did not work. Is it something very obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: You have an extra `}` near the end of your code. Also, I assume `$(footer).height();` should be `$('footer').height();`.

Comment: Removed it! Thanks for that. Also, I changed $(footer) to $('footer'). Still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar [here](http://aramk.com/javascript/floating-elements-on-screen-when-scrolling-past/). I think you'd want to [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to determine the position of the element with respect to the document. Also, `positionToReach` would by the `offset().top` of the footer.

Comment: So something like var footerHeight = $('footer').offset().top; ?

Comment: That would be the footer offset position, not the height. You need to monitor scroll and when the scroll position + window height reaches that offset position you know that the bottom of the window has reached the footer.

Comment: Ok, forgive me, I'm pretty new to this. How about this?
     
     var positionToReach = $('footer').offset().top;
     if( $(document).scrollTop() >= positionToReach ){
          $('aside').removeClass('fixed_aside').addClass('bottom_fixed_aside');
                 } else {
          $('aside').removeClass('bottom_fixed_aside');
                 }